# Localization of FaceBook Events?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When creating page level events, is it possible to hide/show specific events based on region. For example 2 events, one is US based, the other Canada. Can I the Canadian event from the US audience, and vise-versa for the Canadian audience?

Cheers!